# MongoDB DuplicateKeyException

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, mongodb-.net-driver

```
WriteConcern detected an error 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: develop.Test.$AppId_1_UserId_1_Type_1__sub_1__key_1  dup key: { ... }'. (Response was { "ok" : 1, "code" : 11000, "err" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: develop.Test.$AppId_1_UserId_1_Type_1__sub_1__key_1  dup key: {...}).
```

I'm getting the above error when trying to insert a new entry into my collection. The thing that is confusing me is my key is a Guid id field. The entity has AppId and UserId fields but those aren't supposed to be the key and shouldn't have to be unique.

Right before I save the Id is just all zeroes. After it is set to a unique Guid, but the save call throws the MongoDuplicateKey error.
Maybe it's because I'm new to Mongo but I don't understand this any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Output of get Indexes

```
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "develop.Test"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "AppId" : 1,
            "UserId" : 1,
            "Type" : 1,
            "_sub" : 1,
            "_key" : 1
        },
        "name" : "AppId_1_UserId_1_Type_1__sub_1__key_1",
        "ns" : "develop.Test"
    },
    "2" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "Type" : 1,
            "_sub" : 1,
            "_g" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Type_1__sub_1__g_1",
        "ns" : "develop.Test"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the output of `db.collection.getIndexes()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [*unique*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) [*compound indexes*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) on the `AppId`, `UserId`, `Type`, `sub` and `key` fields that is why you are getting this error.

```
"1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "AppId" : 1,
            "UserId" : 1,
            "Type" : 1,
            "_sub" : 1,
            "_key" : 1
        },
        "name" : "AppId_1_UserId_1_Type_1__sub_1__key_1",
        "ns" : "develop.Test"
    },
```

Now how to solve the problem?

- If you didn't create it so perhaps you co-worker or someone did. In this case **you don't drop the index without talking to them**.
- You may want to drop the index using [**`db.collection.dropIndex(index)`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/#db.collection.dropIndex) method

  ```
  db.collection.dropIndex({ AppId: 1, UserId: 1, Type: 1, _sub: 1, _key: 1 })
  ```

Comment: It turned out I just had to change _key to Key! The subject field had a  [BsonElement("_sub")] tag but there wasn't one for Key so _key was always null. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!